# ASP.NET Button vs Linkbutton Enabled="false" behavior

Tags: asp.net, webforms, linkbutton

Why do ASP.NET `LinkButton` controls with `OnClientClick` attribute and disabled by setting `Enabled="false"` still render `onclick` event handler in HTML while `Button` controls don't?

It seems counter-intuitive. Since anchors can't really be disabled in browsers, it makes more sense not to attach an onclick event (and href attribute) if it has been set disabled on server-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I would agree that it doesn't server much purpose, but without changing the way the linkbutton renders with one of the many methods built into asp.net there really isn't anything you can do about it.  Unless you want to conditionally handle clicks in clientside code and check element attributes.  This is just the way it is currently implemented so when you need the functionality of a button that can be disabled it is best to stay way from linkbuttons or anchors entirely.

Answer (score 0):

This really has little to do with asp.net.

A hyperlink button still fires the onclick event even when disabled. Bottom line: baked into HTML. (An input tag, when disabled, does not fire.)

```
 <a href="javascript:alert('Hello!');" disabled="disabled">Click Me!</a>
```

Comment: My point exactly. So why render the href/onclick attributes? If you see disabled Button controls rendered by asp.net, they are set to disabled AND onclick is not rendered (I guess for security purpose).

Comment: input button doesn't fire onclick event when disabled.

Comment: Maybe we are saying the same thing but an input tag / button does not fire the onclick event when disabled (event when when the markup is included.) Maybe asp.net is just optimizing things a bit since the onclick markup is not used / needed.